# What CI servers work well with powershell

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration

I'm currently am working on multiple projects in powershell that are starting to rely on each other, and I need to automate the build and deployment stages. I would also like to get an error report If break the build. Can anyone recommend something for this that will also work with private GitHub repos?

(I'm using pester for my unit and integration tests)

Answer (score 0):

Pester uses standard nUnit formatted XML output that should be compatible with majority of the CI servers. Pester itself uses TeamCity to run the tests. But others use it with success on AppVeyor.
[Original info here](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/251) - But currently it's hosted on Powershell.org community server.